# How to check whether the bar code is already in use?

Tags: barcode

We are going to make a system in PHP which will give information about bar code entered by user. The system will give following information about bar code:

- Give message for whether the entered bar code is valid or not.
- If entered bar code is valid then check whether it is already is in use or not.

We have found the solution for first point but didn't get anything for second point.

So we want to know that, Is there any API or something else that resolve our problem?

Comment: try entering `barcode api` into google or something.  Your scanner vendor may also provide a dll or API.

Answer (score 0):

Make a database containing all created/used barcode then compare it to scanned/enetered barcode.

There is a microsoft created POS for .net for scanners or your scanner has a specific software development kit like in the case of symbol. there's also zxing for reading barcode images stored in pc file.